# Old German ways of saying "in particular"

Tags: expression, history

Is "nämlich so" (or something spelled in a similar way) an abbreviation for an old way of saying "in particular"?  The context I am working with seems to suggest that "in particular" might be the intended meaning.

---

Context:

I'm translating a paper that is from 100 or so years ago. It says:

> Nun kann man einsehen, dass das Integral E die Stetigkeitseigenschaft hat, dass aus lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} B_{n}=R fuer die zugehoerigen E folgt lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E_{n}=E_{R}
>
> **Naemlich so**. Ist ein Bereich B in einem zweiten B' enthalten, so gilt fuer die zugehoerigen Integrale EF^{2} und E'(F')^{2} die Beziehung EF^{2} < E'(F')^{2}.....

So, the sentence with the two limit statements is saying that the regions B_{n} converge to the disk R, and that the integrals E_{n} converge to the E for the disk R. The second statement seems to be saying, "In particular, when B is a subset of B', then the following inequality holds...." Am I wrong?

Comment: Could you please give the context?

Comment: "Naemlich so. Ist ein Bereich B in einem zweiten B' enthalten, so gilt fuer die zugehoerigen Integrale EF^{2} und E'(F')^{2} die Beziehung EF^{2} < E'(F')^{2}....."

Comment: This is following the sentence, "Nun kann man einsehen, dass das Integral E die Stetigkeitseigenschaft hat, dass aus lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} B_{n}=R fuer die zugehoerigen E folgt lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E_{n}=E_{R}"

Comment: So, the sentence with the two limit statements is saying that the regions B_{n} converge to the disk R, and that the integrals E_{n} converge to the E for the disk R.  The second statement (the first one that I posted) seems to be saying, "In particular, when B is a subset of B', then the following inequality holds...."  Am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, the only tag I could find was "old German", but this paper I'm translating is only from 100 or so years ago.

Comment: http://grammarist.com/usage/to-wit

Comment: The relevant part is: Man kann xy einsehen. Nämlich so: *Erklärung, wie man es einsehen kann.*

Comment: The literal translation would be "namely (like this)". But other translations work as well, of course - it is a statement, that something is explained in the following text.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the clarification.  I guess I was right about the sense of the statement, if not the literal translation.

Comment: Ich glaube im Deutschen gibt es keine Wortfolge, die man als Abkürzung einer englischen bezeichnen könnte.

Answer (score 6):

No. If you are precise "nämlich" has nothing to do with "in particular". "Nämlich" has to do with "naming" and making explicit.

> Es ist wirklich jemand gestorben, nämlich Kurt.
>
> Someone did indeed die and that someone is Kurt.

or

> Someone did indeed die, namely Kurt.

"In particular", in my opinion at least, is closer to "especially". Like here:

> The musicians were impressive, the strings in particular.
>
> Die Musiker waren beeindruckend, besonders die Streicher.

Comment: Noted.  In my (limited) experience with upper level mathematics, though, the use of "in particular" appears muddled and perhaps not quite the same as the English usage.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Schön, wie die ursprüngliche Bedeutung eingearbeitet ist.

Answer (score 3):

[Meyers Konversationslexikon](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=100253&textview=true) from the end of 19th century as well as Brockhaus frequently use **namentlich** for stating that relation, as in

> **Absterben einzelner Glieder,** eine eigentümliche Erscheinung, wobei die äußersten Körperteile, namentlich Finger und Zehen, leichenhaft blaß, kalt und empfindungslos werden.